# Activate "Managed Metadata Navigation" feature using CSOM

Tags: managed-metadata, client-object-model, office-365

We're trying to automate a Site Provisoning process but cannot figure out how to activate the Managed Metadata Navigation feature using CSOM.

This is the code we're executing:

```
        var clientSite = ClientContext.Site;
        var clientSiteFeatures = clientSite.Features;
        ClientContext.Load(clientSiteFeatures);
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // Activate the feature
        clientSiteFeatures.Add(featureId, force, scope);
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The ID we're activating (this is SP2013 online) is '7201d6a4-a5d3-49a1-8c19-19c4bac6e668' - online resources tell us this should be the correct one. However, this is the error we receive:

```
Feature with Id '7201d6a4-a5d3-49a1-8c19-19c4bac6e668' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.
```

Activating the feature manually using Site Settings works like a charm, we didn't get any prerequisite warnings. We've tried activating things like publishing and enterprise features, but no luck.

How can we activate the Managed Metadata Navigation feature using CSOM?

Comment: Can you post how the featureId variable is populated

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs since `Metadata Navigation and Filtering (Id: {7201d6a4-a5d3-49a1-8c19-19c4bac6e668})` is a **Web** level feature but your example is intended for activating a Site level features.

The following example demonstrates how to activate `Metadata Navigation and Filtering` feature:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    var featureId = new Guid("7201d6a4-a5d3-49a1-8c19-19c4bac6e668");
    var features = ctx.Web.Features;
    features.Add(featureId, true, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```